# ExtJS: Xtemplate doesn't recognize special characters like /n /r

Tags: extjs, special-characters, store, record, xtemplate

My store record has some special characters as follows

```
name: "Hi \r\n\r\n Location Name: Hello\r\n\r\n"
```

But when it is displayed on UI (using XTemplate), the special characters are not displayed but not even applied. They are just discarded.

//XTemplate

```
    var cars_template = new Ext.XTemplate(
'<tpl =".">',
'<div class="cars-item">',                 
'<li>',
'<span>Name: </span><span>{[this.updateHtml(values.name)]}</span>',
'</li>',
'</div></tpl>',
{
  updateHtml: function(value){
    if(value){
      value = value.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br/>');            
    }
    return value;
  }
}

);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the newlines are not html, they need to be converted to their html equivalent `<br/>` one way or another.

So for a string you could convert new lines like this:

```
var myString = 'Hi \r\n\r\n Location Name: Hello\r\n\r\n';
myString = myString.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br/>');
```

Thanks to Emissary, there is a [built in](https://bt.associatesys.local/documentation/extjs5/ext-docs-5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.util.Format-method-nl2br) function in `ExtJS` to convert to `<br />`:

`Ext.util.Format.nl2br(value)`

[Here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/s0p) is a sencha fiddle with a working example to a `dataview` and below is the corresponding code:

```
var s = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['name'],
            data: [{
                name: "Hi \r\n\r\n Location Name: Hello\r\n\r\n"
            }, {
                name: "Hi \r\n\r\n A Test Here: Another Test\r\n\r\n"
            }]
        });
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            title: 'Example Replacement',
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                xtype:'dataview',
                store: s,
                tpl: [
                '<tpl for=".">', 
                '<div class="cars-item">', 
                '<li>', 
                '<span>Name: </span><span>{[this.updateHtml(values.name)]}</span>', 
                '</li>', 
                '</div>',
                '</tpl>', 
                {
                    updateHtml: function(value) {
                        console.log(value);
                        if (value) {
                            value = value.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br/>');
                        }
                        console.log(value);
                        return value;
                    }
                }
                ],
                multiSelect: true,
                height: 310,
                trackOver: true,
                itemSelector: '.cars-item',
                emptyText: 'Nothing to display'
            }]
        });
```

I `console.log` the change and this is replacing new lines with `<br />`.

Comment: Thank you @weeksdev but how can I integrate it in my example? Could you please check my updated code?

Comment: I even tried to replace the \n\r with some random word to make sure that the replacement is happening but it doesn't work -- value = value.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, 'TEST');

Comment: @KavitaC added an extjs example with a fiddle demonstrating how you could do it with an `dataview`.  Your example above looks right so hopefully you can derive the issue from the working example.

Comment: @KavitaC maybe the missing `for` in the `tpl` `element` was causing your issue?

Comment: *FYI* `Ext.util.Format.nl2br( string )`

Comment: @Emissary good catch, went looking for this in extjs first but couldn't find it.  Here is the [doc for reference](https://bt.associatesys.local/documentation/extjs5/ext-docs-5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.util.Format-method-nl2br). Also added to the answer.

Comment: @weeksdev thank you for all your help!                                                {[this.updateHtml(values.test)]}</span>',
     
      '</div></tpl>',{
        updateHtml: function(value){
          if(value){
            value = value.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br/>');     
          }
          return value;
        }
      }